# Oracle SQL merge multiple columns into datetime stamp

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I currently have a data set with the date and time broken into multiple columns. I'm looking for a solution to create a date timestamp column.

**Here is an example of the fields:**

[image: Year Month StartMonthName Day Hour Min Sec 2020 8 August 3 7 25 18]

**Preferred timestamp: DD-MON-RRRR HH12:MI:SS **

03-AUG-2020 07:25:18

Oracle Version 19.2.1.247

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are datatypes of your columns? What are their exact column names? I wouldn't use `day`, `hour`, `year` for them. And I'd suggest to add virtual hidden calculated column for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE TIMESTAMPS
(
  YEAR NUMBER,
  MONTH NUMBER,
  STARTMONTHNAME VARCHAR2(30),
  DAY NUMBER,
  HOUR NUMBER,
  MIN NUMBER,
  SEC NUMBER
);
  
INSERT INTO TIMESTAMPS VALUES (2020, 8, 'August', 3, 7, 25, 18);
INSERT INTO TIMESTAMPS VALUES (2021, 8, 'August', 3, 7, 25, 18);
```

With your timestamp format.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
       TO_TIMESTAMP(YEAR||'-'||STARTMONTHNAME||'-'||DAY||'-'||HOUR||
       '-'||MIN||'-'||SEC, 'YYYY-MONTH-DD-HH-MI-SS'),
       'DD-MON-RRRR HH12:MI:SS') "TIME"
FROM TIMESTAMPS;
```

For Date

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
       TO_DATE(YEAR||'-'||STARTMONTHNAME||'-'||DAY||'-'||HOUR||
       '-'||MIN||'-'||SEC, 'YYYY-MONTH-DD-HH-MI-SS'),
       'DD-MON-RRRR HH12:MI:SS') "TIME"
FROM TIMESTAMPS;
```

Comment: Thank you - how do I make this query work with multiple records? I'm getting this error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: But make sure you really want Timestamp and not Date, Timestamp has fractions of seconds as well and that's the thing you may not want.

Comment: I did not know that... how do I change it to date?

Comment: You just need to replace to_timestamp with to_date. I have edited my answer.